# Recuperar valor de String en java

Tags: java, string, variables-globales

Estoy intentando hacer un automata en java, y he tenido un problema con una variable tipo String declarada como global y sin inicializar. A la hora de ejecutar el método en el cual se ejecuta el automata y el recorrido que debe hacer, se modifica el contenido de la variable String llamada "impresionExcel". El inconveniente viene de que me doy cuenta que el contenido de dicha variable no se ve modificado. Sigue apuntando a null a pesar de que dependiendo la situación debería almacenar distinta información. Ojalá alguien pueda resolver mi duda respecto a qué está pasando. Muchas gracias. El siguiente código es unicamente del método del recorrido del automata y hasta arriba como esta declarada la variable.

```
static String impresionExcel;

public void ejecuta(Interfaz interfaz) {
    this.interfaz = interfaz;
    char primer = cadena.getCadena().charAt(0);
    if (primer != '0' && primer != '1' && primer != '2' && primer != '3' && primer != '4' && primer != '5' && primer != '6' && primer != '7' && primer != '8' && primer != '9'&& primer != '.'&& primer != '+'&& primer != '-') {
        circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
        interfaz.getPortada().add(circulo);
        interfaz.getLblProcesando().setText("Cadena NO Aceptada");
        impresionExcel = "Cadena no aceptada.";
        EscribirEXCEL();
        return;
    }

    interfaz.getBtnAutomata1().setEnabled(false);
    interfaz.getBtnInsertarCadena().setEnabled(false);
    interfaz.getLblProcesando().setText("Procesando...");

    if (automata.getAutomata() == 1) {
        recorrido = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
        interfaz.getPortada().add(circulo);
        recorrido.add(0);
        while (fin == false) {
            if (posCadena > cadena.getCadena().length() - 1) {
                fin = true;
                break;
            }
            char actual = cadena.getCadena().charAt(posCadena);
            if (posAct == 0) {
                circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
                if (actual == '0' || actual == '1' || actual == '2' || actual == '3' || actual == '4' || actual == '5' || actual == '6' || actual == '7' || actual == '8' || actual == '9') {
                    posAct = 1;
                    recorrido.add(1);
                }else if(actual == '+' || actual == '-'|| actual == '.'){
                    posAct = 2;
                    recorrido.add(2);
                }else {
                    impresionExcel = "Carácter no válido. Acepta . ó + ó - ó digito.";
                    EscribirEXCEL();
                    fin = true;
                    break;
                }
                posCadena++;
                continue;
            }
            if (posAct == 1) {
                circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
                if (actual == '0' || actual == '1' || actual == '2' || actual == '3' || actual == '4' || actual == '5' || actual == '6' || actual == '7' || actual == '8' || actual == '9') {
                    posAct = 1;
                    recorrido.add(1);
                } else if (actual == 'E' || actual == 'e') {
                    posAct = 5;
                    recorrido.add(5);
                } else if (actual == '.') {
                    posAct = 3;
                    recorrido.add(3);
                } else {
                    impresionExcel = "Carácter no válido. Debe ser . ó E ó dígito.";
                    EscribirEXCEL();
                    fin = true;
                    break;
                }
                posCadena++;
                continue;
            }
            if (posAct == 2) {
                circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
                if (actual == '0' || actual == '1' || actual == '2' || actual == '3' || actual == '4' || actual == '5' || actual == '6' || actual == '7' || actual == '8' || actual == '9') {
                    posAct = 1;
                    recorrido.add(1);
                } else {
                    impresionExcel = "Carácter no válido. Debe ser un digito.";
                    EscribirEXCEL();
                    fin = true;
                    break;
                }
                posCadena++;
                continue;
            }
            if (posAct == 3) {
                circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
                if (actual == '0' || actual == '1' || actual == '2' || actual == '3' || actual == '4' || actual == '5' || actual == '6' || actual == '7' || actual == '8' || actual == '9') {
                    posAct = 4;
                    recorrido.add(4);
                } else {
                    impresionExcel = "Carácter no válido. Debe ser un digito.";
                    EscribirEXCEL();
                    fin = true;
                    break;
                }
                posCadena++;
                continue;
            }
            if (posAct == 4) {
                circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
                if (actual == '0' || actual == '1' || actual == '2' || actual == '3' || actual == '4' || actual == '5' || actual == '6' || actual == '7' || actual == '8' || actual == '9') {
                    posAct = 4;
                    recorrido.add(4);
                } else if (actual == 'E' || actual == 'e') {
                    posAct = 5;
                    recorrido.add(5);
                } else {
                    impresionExcel = "Carácter no válido. Acepta E ó un digito.";
                    EscribirEXCEL();
                    fin = true;
                    break;
                }
                posCadena++;
                continue;
            }
            if (posAct == 5) {
                circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
                if (actual == '0' || actual == '1' || actual == '2' || actual == '3' || actual == '4' || actual == '5' || actual == '6' || actual == '7' || actual == '8' || actual == '9') {
                    posAct = 7;
                    recorrido.add(7);
                }else if (actual == '+' || actual == '-') {
                    posAct = 6;
                    recorrido.add(6);
                }else {
                    impresionExcel = "Carácter no válido. Debe ser . ó E.";
                    EscribirEXCEL();
                    fin = true;
                    break;
                }
                posCadena++;
                continue;
            }
            if (posAct == 6) {
                circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
                if (actual == '0' || actual == '1' || actual == '2' || actual == '3' || actual == '4' || actual == '5' || actual == '6' || actual == '7' || actual == '8' || actual == '9') {
                    posAct = 7;
                    recorrido.add(7);
                } else {
                    impresionExcel = "Carácter no válido. Debe ser un digito.";
                    EscribirEXCEL();
                    fin = true;
                    break;
                }
                posCadena++;
                continue;
            }
            if (posAct == 7) {
                circulo.setBounds(xyAut1[0][posAct], xyAut1[1][posAct], 40, 41);
                if (actual == '0' || actual == '1' || actual == '2' || actual == '3' || actual == '4' || actual == '5' || actual == '6' || actual == '7' || actual == '8' || actual == '9') {
                    posAct = 7;
                    recorrido.add(7);
                } else {
                    impresionExcel = "Carácter no válido. Debe ser un digito.";
                    EscribirEXCEL();
                    fin = true;
                    break;
                }
                posCadena++;
                continue;
            }
        }

    }
    ejecutaRecorrido();
}
```

Comment: Creo que debe inicializarla y mejor colocarle un método de acceso, `public static String impresionExcel = "";`

Comment: Has depurado el código y estas seguro de que en algún momento le das valor a la variable?

Comment: Estaba pensando lo mismo, puede ser que las diferentes condiciones (`if`) que hay en el código nunca se cumplan y por ende la variable no se actualiza

Comment: Ya la inicialicé así y como public static, pero aún si no se actualiza la variable. En ocasiones algún if se cumple y aún así la variables me queda como null ó "".

Answer (score 1):

Las varibalkes static deben usarse   asi:

```
class ClaseX {
    static String variable;
   ...
}
```

y se usan así:

```
ClaseX.variable
```

mas no así:

```
variable
```